# Write Data Early Bios option

Tags: bios, supermicro

Some BIOS include this option:

```
Write Data Early: Enable/[Disable]
```

For example, in the Supermicro BIOS' it's under Advanced/Chipset/Northbridge, where it's disabled, by default. (Unfortunately, the Supermicro manual doesn't explain this option.)

What does 'write data early' mean is this context?

What are the advantages of enabling/disabling it?

Answer (score 1):

It *should* be a timing optimization for buffered and/or fully buffered DIMM. It basically allow to lower the latency by some cycles. I can't find anything Intel specific, but you can give a look at [this Google patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8745321)

Comment: Is this the same mechanism that is described in the [Intel Xeon Phi Datasheet](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/xeon-phi-processor-x200-product-family-vol-2-datasheet.pdf) (page 68): 'dis_ddrio_earlywdata — Disable sending write data early to DDRIO for anti cross talk logic; If 0, data will be sent
early one Dclock so DDRIO has time to do cross talk cancellation logic.
If set to 1, write data will be sent with normal timing and DDRIO will have no time to do cross talk cancellation logic.' ? You mean you lower the latency if write-data-early is enabled?

Comment: @maxschlepzig Xeon Phi was a completely different beast, with no support for FBDIMM and/or buffer memory chip, so I am not sure "Write Data Early" is the same thing as for "normal" Xeon.